# VIM: Why is the dot operator working differently?

Tags: vim

I want to understand what gets stored in Vim's dot(.) register.

Consider the following text:

```
This is Line one
This is Line two
This is Line three
```

With the cursor on the first line, if I do `A;<esc>` I can repeat the same action for the next line by `j.`

However, if I do the action like removing the last character on the first line by `$x` and then try to repeat it for the next line by `j.`, it is not removing the last character of the line, instead it just deletes the character under the cursor.

So why is dot command able to remember the position in the first example `A;<esc>` whereas not able to do the same for `$x` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From `:help .`:

```
.                       Repeat last change, with count replaced with [count].
                        Also repeat a yank command, when the 'y' flag is
                        included in 'cpoptions'.  Does not repeat a
                        command-line command.
```

With `A;`, the change is to insert a `;` at the end of the current line. `A` moves the cursor and switches to insert mode.

With `$x`, the `$` first moves the cursor, then the `x` command deletes a character. They are not linked together, so the change is only the deletion of the character at the current cursor position.

(Put another way, the motion is only part of the change if the command takes a motion operator *after* the command, like `d`, or if the motion is implicit in the command, like with `A`.)